# SQL query to retrive data

Tags: mysql, sql

For these relations:

```
Customer(CID, Name, City, State),
Order(OID, CID, Date), and
Product(PID, ProductName, Price)
LineItem(LID, OID,PID, Number, TotalPrice),
```

where CID is a customer id and is a key for Customer, OID is an order id and is a key for Order, and LID is a line item id and is a key for LineItem. In addition the attribute CID of Order is a foreign key referring to the CID of Customer, that is, for each CID c of Order there is exactly one tuple of Customer whose CID attribute is c. The OID of LineItem is a foreign key referring to the OID of Order. There are several line items for the same order, a line item refers to a product and contains the quantity ordered for the product.

What is the query for:
List the products bought by all the customers of 'mycity'

@Edit
This is what I've tried so far:

```
Select ProductName 
from Product 
where PID in (
    select PID 
    from LineItem 
    where OID in(
        Select OID 
        from Order 
        where CID in(
            select CID from customer where city='mycity'
        )
    )
);
```

This query however will return all the products bought by all customers from mycity. And the question requires only those products that everyone from 'mycity' have bought.

Not sure how to implement "All in" condition

@Edit2: Finally solved it :) Can someone please verify??

Comment: Show what queries you have tried so far

Comment: hrdasadia - You will never learn how to do this yourself if someone just gives you the answer.  Make an attempt and post it.  You'll thank me later when you take your test. :-)

Comment: There are no slaves here to do the work for you. Try to solve the problem yourself and eventually post it here along with your code.

Comment: Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: I agree with all of you and what you're saying but sometimes you can't really show what you're trying not because you didn't try anything but because you think what you're trying is far from being right

Comment: @CodeBird That is precisely the reason why it must be shown! If there are any attempts to solve the problem then they should be posted, in order to help the author see the mistakes. If there's no evidence of the attepmted solution, there's no way to help the author understand what is wrong with his/her approach. Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Quoting from the article: *"When you’re asked what have you tried?, it doesn’t mean “show me the code you’ve written, or piss off”. What you have to do is at least try to help yourself – and the trying is the important thing."*

Comment: @Barranka I totally agree, but sometimes comments and answers makes a person really feel stupid :)

Comment: In all cases this is no place to discuss that, and I agree with you and the article you posted...

Comment: @SamD: Yes, it is part of HW and I am somehow not able to think straight.

Comment: @Sparky: I agree. Had already tried attempting but forgot to post it :(

Comment: @Barranka: I get it. Any software professional worth his salt gives it a shot himself.

Comment: @CodeBird: Thanks for support mate.. That's exactly how I felt while posting this. Nonetheless, I should've posted my attempt.

Comment: @Michal I did try solving it myself. Did not intend to make you/anyone feel like a slave.

Comment: @simpleJack Your approach uses nested selects in where conditions; that may give you the solution, but it is expensive and does not exploits the SQL real power: relate data. Read about `join`s.

Comment: @Barranka : CodeBird has used joins and that returns a faulty answer too. I can use joins but how to ensure that all customers from a city bought a product??

Comment: @Everyone: Can someone please verify? I have spend all day doing this.

Comment: @RickS: I took your advise :) Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better version in a single query:

```
select p1.productname from Product p1, myorder s1, lineitem l1, customer c1
where l1.pid=p1.pid
and l1.OID=s1.oid
and c1.cid=s1.cid
and c1.city='mycity'
group by p1.ProductName
having count(distinct c1.cid)=(select count(1) from customer c2 where c2.city='mycity');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProductName FROM Product 
INNER JOIN LineItem ON LineItem.PID=Product.PID 
INNER JOIN `Order` ON Order.OID=LineItem.OID 
INNER JOIN Customer ON Order.CID=Customer.CID 
WHERE Customer.City='mycity'
```

I think this should work

Comment: This does not work as it will return all the products purchased by customers of 'mycity' even if the product is purchased by one. I want the products that all the customers of 'mycity' have bought. So, say everyone from 'mycity' buys a laptop, then thats the only product my query must return.

Answer (score 0):

This query is solved in 2 parts: Create a view and query that view

```
Create view hview as (SELECT distinct count(distinct Customer.CID) as
uniquecustomer, count(distinct Customer.name), product.pid, product.Productname
FROM myorder
INNER JOIN Customer ON myorder.CID = Customer.CID
INNER JOIN LineItem ON myorder.OID = LineItem.oid
INNER JOIN Product ON Product.PID = LineItem.PID
where Customer.city = 'mycity'
group by Product.PID);


select productname from product where pid in(
select PID from hview where uniquecustomer in( SELECT count(distinct Customer.CID)
FROM myorder
INNER JOIN Customer ON myorder.CID = Customer.CID
INNER JOIN LineItem ON myorder.OID = LineItem.oid
INNER JOIN Product ON Product.PID = LineItem.PID
where Customer.city = 'mycity'));
```

Logic Used: create a view of items with distinct owners from mycity.
Query that view to find items that have distinct owners equal to number of distinct customers in mycity. Every item that has a distinct number of owners equal to the number of distinct customers of mycity are the products that are bought by everyone in mycity.

*myorder is the table name I used instead of order since thats a reserve word.